# What is thermal radiation? How does it move through space?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Assume that by some mysterious(at the lack of a better word) way I was able to make a bonfire on the moon and was able to sit next to it without a space suit.

I will not be able to feel the heat form the fire as a result of convection as there is no atmosphere

Now my question is will I be able to feel the heat from the fire as a result of radiation?
As far as I know a wood fire does not produce electromagnetic waves or does it?

In short what is thermal radiation?

Comment: If a wood fire was burning on the moon, it would need an $O_2$ supply and would be producing hot $CO_2$ as a consequence of combustion, which you would be able to feel as heat by convection. To your question: yes a fire produces light (electromagnetic waves). This is how torches provide lighting in dark caves. Thermal radiation is light that you just happen to be unable to see (with human eyes).

Comment: I see your point, thus thermal radiation is light outside the visible spectrum, infrared?

Comment: If you sit in front of a fire on earth, you feel the IR radiation.  People who wear glasses know this: our eyes are much more comfortable with our glasses on, blocking the IR radiation.  Same would be true on the Moon, if you could build a fire there.

Comment: If you heat up an iron rod, as it increases in temperature it goes from not glowing to glowing red - > yellow -> white. As the temperature of an object goes up, the wavelength of the light emitted gets smaller. Objects at room temperature mostly emit in the infrared (iron rod before it starts glowing). Once their temperature is high enough the wavelength enters the visible range. However, a glowing hot iron is still emitting in the infrared range. Just now it is also emitting in the visible. *All* of that radiation, visible and invisible, due to temperature is called "thermal radiation"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I will not be able to feel the heat form the fire as a result of convection as there is no atmosphere

True, but no atmosphere also means no oxygen for the fire, so this example is kind'a off.

> Now my question is will I be able to feel the heat from the fire as a result of radiation?

Yes.

If the fire was at Earth (in an atmosphere with oxygen) the strong heat you feel when holding your hands above the fire is from natural convection. But standing beside the fire, you still feel the heat. Convection cannot be the cause of this, if no wind is moving hot air your way - instead this is due to *thermal radiation*.

> As far as I know a wood fire does not produce electromagnetic waves or does it?

Yes, it does.

Any material with a non-zero temperature produces thermal radiation - this is simply a type of electromagnetic wave. You own body radiates heat, and anything else you see around you radiates heat. Stefan-Boltzmann's law describes this:

$$I=\epsilon \sigma T^4$$

($I$ is heat from each square meter $[W/m^2]$ as thermal radiation, $\epsilon$ the emmisivity (how well the object radiates heat), $\sigma$ the Boltzmann's constant, $T$ the temperature.)

> In short what is thermal radiation?

The thermal radiation is electromagnetic waves as any other kind of radiation. If you can see fire, sparks, lightning etc. the temperature is so that the electromagnetic waves are in the visible spectrum. As a red-hot iron bar. If not, then you can't see the radiation - but it still is there outside of the visible spectrum (in the infrared part most likely).

[image]

One can from Wien's displacement law see that higher temperature apart from radiating more strongly, also shifts the wavelenghts of the radiation towards lower values - towards the visible spectrum:

[image]